# Create a Discord channel upon receiving DMs

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

So I'm working on a bot, and I'd like it to have it's own ticket support system.

What I'd like it to do is that, upon receiving a DM it:
- Creates a new channel named after the DM author (such as #David0001) in a "ticket" category
- Sets up permissions for that channel to be only accessible to read and write by the DM author (and admins ofc)
- Restranscribes whatever the DM author wrote in his DM

I'm currently using the latest Async discord.py branch (I know I should probably be using rewrite but oh well)

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.server is None and message.author != client.user:
        server = client.get_server("serverid")
        for channel in server.channels:
            if channel.name == str(message.author):
                await client.send_message(message.author, "Hey you already have a support ticket open!")
                break
            else:
                await client.create_channel(server, str(message.author), type=discord.ChannelType.text)
                overwrite = discord.PermissionOverwrite()
                overwrite.read_messages = True
                overwrite.send_messages = True
                overwrite.ban_members = False
                for channel in server.channels:
                    if channel.name == str(message.author):
                        await client.edit_channel_permissions(channel.id, message.author, overwrite)
                        await client.send_message(channel.id, message.content)
                        break
                    else:
                        break
                break
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

I'd also like it to verify first if a support channel with the users name doesn't already exist and if so to send a little message like "hey you already have a support ticket channel open"

This code seems to work at first but not well, it does create a "david0001" channel upon DM, however it doesn't set up the permissions properly, doesn't set it up in a pre-existing ticket catgeory (cause I don't know how to do that), it does not retranscribe whatever the user wrote in the DMs and it does not verify if the user has a open channel, it just keeps making a new one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is multiple solutions that can be proposed for your situation :

> As the old async branch is depreciated, here is the up to date code.

#### Through a command :

I assume you're using a **cog** system :

This is a **command** designed for your request, when the user uses it, it inspect the support server, if there is no **Support** category, it creates one, and creates a channel for the user. If the requirement already exist it just send the message stored in `request` into the correct channel.

```py
import asyncio, discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get

class Cmd_support(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command()
    async def support(self, ctx, *, request: str):

        user = ctx.message.author
        guild_id = 000000000000000000 # fill it up with your support guild id
        support_server = self.client.get_guild(guild_id)

        # try to match with a channel name
        match = False

        for channel in support_server.text_channels:
            await asyncio.sleep(0)

            if channel.name == user.name.lower():  # it's a match
                match = True
                user_support = get(support_server.text_channels, name = user.name.lower())  # get the user support channel as lower case, just like channels name
                break

        # end for

        if not match:  # if the channel doesn't exist, we create it

            support_category_name = 'Support'  # defines the Support category name, case sensitive
            support_category = get(support_server.categories, name = support_category_name)  # get the support category
            user_support = get(support_server.text_channels, name = user.name.lower())  # get the user support channel as lower case, just like channels name

            if support_category == None:  # if the category is not found, we create it
                # setting up the category permissions
                support_category_permissions = {
                    support_server.default_role : discord.PermissionOverwrite(send_messages = False)
                }

                await support_server.create_category(name = support_category_name, overwrites = support_category_permissions)

                support_category = get(support_server.categories, name = support_category_name)  # redefine the variable with the new category

            if user_support == None:  # if the channel doesn't exist

                # setting up the permissions for the channel
                user_channel_permissions = {
                    support_server.default_role : discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages = False, send_messages = False),  # othe users cannot see the channels
                    support_server.me : discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages = True, send_messages = True),
                    user : discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages = True, send_messages = True)
                }

                # now we create the channel
                await support_server.create_text_channel(name = user.name, overwrites = user_channel_permissions, category = support_category)
                user_support = get(support_server.text_channels, name = user.name.lower())  # redefine the support channel

        # now send the message to the new channel
        await user_support.send(request)  # sends what the user sent to the command

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Cmd_support(client))
```

#### Using DMs :

It's slightly different from the command solution, `request` is just replaced by `message.content` and we add the condition :

> Please note that it will create a channel and send message into it no matter the message content. You can filter it by using a condition like : `if message.content.startswith("something"):`

```py
if type(message.channel) == discord.DMchannel:
```

Here's the code :

```py
    @commands.Cog.listener()  # equivalent to discord.Event
    async def on_message(self, message):

        if type(message.channel) == discord.DMChannel:
            user = message.author
            guild_id = 000000000000000000 # fill it up with your support guild id
            support_server = self.client.get_guild(guild_id)

            # try to match with a channel name
            match = False

            for channel in support_server.text_channels:
                await asyncio.sleep(0)

                if channel.name == user.name.lower():  # it's a match
                    match = True
                    user_support = get(support_server.text_channels, name = user.name.lower())  # get the user support channel as lower case, just like channels name
                    break

            # end for

            if not match:  # if the channel doesn't exist, we create it

                support_category_name = 'Support'  # defines the Support category name, case sensitive
                support_category = get(support_server.categories, name = support_category_name)  # get the support category
                user_support = get(support_server.text_channels, name = user.name.lower())  # get the user support channel as lower case, just like channels name

                if support_category == None:  # if the category is not found, we create it
                    # setting up the category permissions
                    support_category_permissions = {
                        support_server.default_role : discord.PermissionOverwrite(send_messages = False)
                    }

                    await support_server.create_category(name = support_category_name, overwrites = support_category_permissions)

                    support_category = get(support_server.categories, name = support_category_name)  # redefine the variable with the new category

                if user_support == None:  # if the channel doesn't exist

                    # setting up the permissions for the channel
                    user_channel_permissions = {
                        support_server.default_role : discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages = False, send_messages = False),  # othe users cannot see the channels
                        support_server.me : discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages = True, send_messages = True),
                        user : discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages = True, send_messages = True)
                    }

                    # now we create the channel
                    await support_server.create_text_channel(name = user.name, overwrites = user_channel_permissions, category = support_category)
                    user_support = get(support_server.text_channels, name = user.name.lower())  # redefine the support channel

            # now send the message to the new channel
            await user_support.send(message.content)  # sends what the user sent to the command

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Event_on_message(client))
```

As you can see it's not that different from the first solution I've proposed.

#### Get the latest discord.py

Well, you should really update your `discord.py` version to the latest, the old `async` branch doesn't exist anymore and has been replaced by the `rewrite` version they were working on.
Try this little script in your **terminal** :

```py
>>> import discord
>>> discord.__version__
'1.2.3'
```

If your version is like **0.X.X** you're not up to date !
Think about `pip install discord.py --upgrade` to get the latest version (it's so much better than the old async one)

Usefull link : [discord.py - Migrating to v1.0](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html) (I've migrated to the new version in few hours, it wasn't too long. You should better migrate now, before your code becomes too big)

Hope it helped ! 
Have a nice day !